# Is baggage has some meaning about slut?

Tags: word-meaning

What's the relation about behind the two words?

slut always likes to take a baggage and move here and where?

And in what cases we use the baggage[less people know] to instead of slut[more people know]?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? It isn't very understandable or answerable as-is; DJ has done an excellent job in doing so regardless, but that required the esoteric knowledge that "baggage" used to be slang for prostitute. Your example sentence doesn't make sense, it would be much appreciated if you could edit for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

[Baggage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/baggage) has a couple different meanings. The most common meaning is the first one in that link, or

> trunks, suitcases, etc., used in traveling; luggage.

The second most common meaning that I know of is the third on in that link, or

> things that encumber one's freedom, progress, development, or adaptability; impediments:

As in, emotional baggage. Apparently, baggage used to be a derogatory term for a prostitute, but this is an outdated usage. I didn't even know that until I looked for the definition of the word.

The word "slut" means

> an immoral or dissolute woman; prostitute.

So really, they mean the same thing. The only difference is that "slut" is still used as a offensive term for an immoral woman, but "baggage" does not mean that any more.

As for when to use them, don't ever say "baggage" unless you're referring to one of the other meanings. Otherwise, nobody will understand you. If you really must use a word for this, (even though it is an offensive word that I recommend you avoid saying) "slut" is a much more appropriate word.